# Auto complete extender issue in ASP

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete with space between 2 fields with the following query::

```
Select  Email+ ' '  + family AS AllName 
FROM userpass 
WHERE Email like '%' + '" + prefixText + + "' + '%' OR 
      family like '%' + '" + prefixText + "' + '%' 
ORDER BY Email,family
```

and in asp.ent:

```
CompletionListCssClass ="AutoExtender" 
FirstRowSelected="true"
MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="GetSpeciesInfo" CompletionInterval="1" EnableCaching="true" completionsetcount="1"  
TargetControlID="TextBox1" ServicePath="~/WebService.asmx" DelimiterCharacters=" " 
ShowOnlyCurrentWordInCompletionListItem="true"  EnableViewState="true"
```

It's working **But** Problem:

When I type space and then write next word autocomplete good work but with word before space combined i.e sample:

> *alek satriani*

When I write alek and space and then select from autocomplete result in textbox will be

> **alek** alek satriani

Comment: really anybody can't reply to my qoustion??

Comment: Check you SQL query. WHERE condition should be like :   WHERE Email like '%'+prefixText +'%' OR 
      family  like '%'+prefixText +'%'